# Помогите сделать выбор - отдельный процесс или же отдельный поток во flask?

Tags: python, flask

Решил сделать систему отопления у себя в квартире.

Отопления газовое, автономное (газовый котёл в квартире).

В качестве контроллера управления `raspberry pi`.

По квартире брошены датчики `ds18b20`.

Захотелось управлять отоплением через web интерфейс, создавать расписания и настройки работы системы.

Все настройки хранятся в базе данных. Выбор пал на `flask+lighttpd`. `Python` и `flask` начал изучать недавно, так что просьба, если задаю глупые вопросы, ногами не бить.

**Так вот вопрос**, как лучше сделать?

Код температурного регулятора написать в самом flaske или же его вынести в отдельный (не зависящий от flask) файл (модуль)? Скажем так запустить отдельным процессом.

Если в самом `flask`, то создавать отдельный поток?

Как я понимаю в таком случае разделяемый ресурс у меня будет база данных.

Кстати использую `flask-sqlalchemy` и сессии я так понимаю не позволят испортить данные в базе в случае одновременной работы с записями.

Answer (score 1):

> Код температурного регулятора написать в самом flaske или же его вынести в отдельный (не зависящий от flask) файл (модуль)? Скажем так запустить отдельным процессом.

Как код организован (как он разбит на модули) и сколько процессов используется для его выполнения—никак не связано. Можно один модуль как несколько процессов запустить и естественно несколько модулей можно внутри одного процесса использовать.

Начните с самого простого: с одного модуля, содержащего как веб-приложение так и утилиты для работы с термостатом, которые оно использует. Если эти утилиты понадобятся где-то вне вашего веб-приложения, то может быть удобно  их в отдельный модуль вытащить.

Если данные хранятся во внешней базе данных, то не имеет значения процесс или потоки используются (нет общих данных в памяти). Чтобы избежать случайного использования общих данных, можно использовать отдельные процессы даже в тех случаях когда потоков было бы достаточно (как правило, достаточно один `import` или конфигурационную опцию поменять, чтобы переключиться с одного на другое).

Comment: jfs хотелось бы уточнить. Что значит внешняя база данных? Я использую sqlite. Создавалась во Flaske путём импорта flask-sqlalchemy и других модулей.

Comment: @ЖанБещанов: sqlite это *встроенный* движок, поэтому пытаясь использовать его из нескольких потоков, процессов вы против течения работаете (поддержка есть, но она присутствует "не смотря на"). `sqlalchemy` позволяет относительно легко сменить движок, например, на postgresql. Но если база существует только для вашего приложения, то прежде чем усложнять, нужно больше услышать кто что в базу пишет, и кто что читать должен—может вам стоит спросить отдельный вопрос "как организовать проект в целом": опишите *что* вы хотите, чтобы ваша система делала плюс *как* вы её сейчас организуете и почему.

Comment: по поводу sqlite и встроенного движка, что то я в первый раз об этом слышу. Я так понимаю, что sqlite не совсем для параллельного использования несколькими потоками? MySQL и  postgresql больше подходят для параллельного использования? Вообще flask я изучаю по книге и блогу Мигеля Гринберга. У меня всё тоже самое, что и у него, только приложение не для блогинга, а для управления отоплением. Также я использую web-socketы для динамической интерактивности. Если организовывать отдельный вопрос (тему), то получается этот вопрос надо закрывать?

Comment: @ЖанБещанов embedded это второе слово [в официальном описании SQLite](http://sqlite.org/). Комментарии не подходящее место обсуждать достоинства и недостатки выбора технологии хранения данных. Закрывать ничего не надо—Stack Overflow  сайт это не форум в традиционном понимании. Он существует не для обсуждений, а чтобы ответы  на конкретные практические вопросы аккумулировать. Текущий вопрос слишком абстрактный без необходимых деталей и поэтому не слишком полезен. Подумайте как задать вопросы, чтобы полезный ответ можно было в один/два абзаца поместить.

Comment: я понял. Подумаю над конкретными вопросами, чтобы получить конкретный ответ. Спасибо.